# Understanding of Rounding IEEE Floating PointNumber

Tags: floating-point, rounding, verilog, ieee-754

I am writing a rounding scheme for a Floating point adder.I don't know what happens for a few values, I tried reading the manual but can't figure it out. To code , I can think of `if .. else` or `case` statement,but is there a better way of coding in Verilog?
G - Guard
R - Round
S - Sticky Bit

```
G  R  S    Value

0  X  X    Value;
1  0  0    Value = ?
1  0  1    Value = ?
1  1  0    Value = ?
1  1  1    Value + 1;
```

Comment: I have to round it to even , but it will be good to know other schemes also

Comment: Could you, for the benefit of the reader, include what you mean by G, R, and S? Is this for the last bit or any bit of the mantissa, what have you already done with the exponent, etc.?

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Yes this is for the last bit of the result. I have taken care of exponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To round to nearest even:

When G R S is 1 0 0, the number is exactly half-way between two floating-point numbers (the fact that the sticky bit is zero means that if you had computed all bits, they would all be zeroes, so the result really is exactly in the middle of Value and Value+1). Round to the even one.

When G R S is 1 0 1 or 1 1 0, the number is above the midpoint. Round up.